# Editing Dynamic Promise in Component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a component that takes a Promise as an input:

```
export class Component  {
    @Input() appendingFunction: Promise<PagedData<any>>
}
```

The "appendingFunction" could look like this:

```
async foo(importantParameter, parameter1,..parameter n): Promise<PagedData<City>>
```

Now before resolving `appendingFunction` i want to set `importantParameter`. I know that it will be present, but i don't know how to define that.
I don't care about any of the other parameters that might be there.

**How do i do this?**

*Complete structure:*

Outside Component 1:

```
export class OutsideComponent1{
   async foo(importantParameter, x):Promise<PagedData<boolean>>{
   ...
   }
}
```

Outside Component 2:

```
export class OutsideComponent2{
   async foo(importantParameter, x, y, z):Promise<PagedData<number>>{
   ...
   }
}
```

HTML for both:

```
<inner-component [appendingFunction]="foo()"></inner-component>
```

Inner Component:

```
export class InnerComponent  {
    @Input() appendingFunction: Promise<PagedData<any>>

onClick(){
  //thats what i would need
  appendingFunction.setImportantParameter();
   appendingFunction.then(() => doSomething)

}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I want to build a pagination-component that takes a function for loading more elements. The function always takes page and pagesize as parameters and might have additional params

Answer (score 1):

I recommend thinking about your solution a little differently.

You can create a service, `AppendingBridgeService`, as follows:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppendingBridgeService {
  private _importantParam = new Subject<any>();
  importantParam$ = this._importantParam.asObservable();

  constructor() {}

  public next(nextParam: string) {
    this._importantParam.next(nextParam);
  }
}
```

Then, in your `Outside` components, declare this service as a dependency:

```
export class OutsideComponent1{
  constructor(abs: AppendingBridgeService) {
    this.abs.importantParam$.subscribe(nextParam => {
      this.foo(nextParam, x).then(pagedData => {
        doSomething;
      });
    });
  } 
}
```

Then, tie the inner component to the same bridge service as such:

```
export class InnerComponent  {
    constructor(abs: AppendingBridgeService) { }

    onClick(){
        this.abs.next(importantParameter);
    }
}
```

Lastly, if you want to tie the inner component to the result of the promise in the `Outside` components, you could create another bridge service that goes the other way and takes in another type, in your case, `PagedData<any>`.

Comment: This is pretty close, requiring the service in the Outside component is a problem though, because this should become reusable. If i need to do it like this, i can just put the appendingfunction in the Outside component, so i would not have an actual benefit